# How to send an request to an action via another action by using AJAX from html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, request, asp.net-ajax, redirecttoaction

I want to send a request to an Action `AAA` by using `AJAX POST/JSON` data from html which is called `HHH` and when Action `AAA` receives the data, it will return `RedirectToAction` to another Action `BBB`.

When action `BBB` receives the POST/JSON request from `AAA`, `BBB` will return `JSON` back to html `HHH`.

Here's the logic:

```
HHH(AJAX) -> AAA(return RedirectToAction) -> BBB(return JSON) -> HHH(not sure)
```

but `HHH` doesn't work! it doesn't receive the data from `BBB`. The

```
success:function(data) {
    ...
}
```

in `HHH`, doesn't work.

I just want to figure out that my logic is correct or not, because i'm not sure that `BBB` can actually return JSON back to `HHH`.

How should I accomplish the whole logic?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to show how to call action with Ajax and Redirect to Action.
Note that the default attribute is HttpGet

Create a button in the view

```
<button type="button" value="ok" id="bntCallAction" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Add the code to the Button on click event

```
$("bntCallAction").one('click', function () {

    $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AAA", "HomeController")',
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
       if (response.success==true) {
        alert(response.responseText);
        }
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
      });       
    );
}
```

Add the Action to the controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AAA()
{
   return RedirectToAction("BBB"); 
}

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult BBB()
{
    bool success = false;
    string sMessage = "Call from BBB Function";   
    return Json(new { success = true, response = sMessage }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
}
```